# Staggered Gridview layout inflater overlapping fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, gridview, layout-inflater

I'm attempting to implement a staggered gridview via this [tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/pinterest-masonry-layout-staggered-grid/). I'm having trouble inflating the staggered gridview within a fragment. The staggered grid view overlaps all fragments in my app.

[Screenshot of overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXQ8t.png)

I believe the problem may lie within here

```
  @Override
public MasonryView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, parent, false);
    MasonryView masonryView = new MasonryView(layoutView);
    return masonryView;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MasonryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MasonryAdapter.MasonryView> {

private Context context;

int[] imgList = {R.drawable.two, R.drawable.one, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four,
        R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
        R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.ten};

String[] nameList = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
        "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"};

public MasonryAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MasonryView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    MasonryView masonryView = new MasonryView(layoutView);
    return masonryView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MasonryView holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(imgList[position]);
    holder.textView.setText(nameList[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nameList.length;
}

class MasonryView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public MasonryView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_name);

    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.masonry_grid);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    MasonryAdapter adapter = new MasonryAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(16);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```